# Java URL downloading HTML content instead of file?

Tags: java, http, url

I am trying to download file using Java URL class, but it is downloading HTML content instead.

```
 class DownloadFileHttpCilent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                    "https://url");
            String encoding=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("abcd:pwd").getBytes());
            request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            System.out.println("Request Url: " + request.getURI());
            System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

            InputStream is = entity.getContent();

            String filePath = "c:\\file1.zip";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));

            int inByte;
            while ((inByte = is.read()) != -1) {
                fos.write(inByte);
            }

            is.close();
            fos.close();

            client.close();
            System.out.println("File Download Completed!!!");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

For other open source URLs, it's working fine, but only in this case, in which it is password protected, it is downloading HTML content.

Output:

```
Request Url: https://abcd.cahj.com/defj
Response Code: 200
File Download Completed!!!
```

Comment: The html should give you a hint about what the problem is. I guess it contains a http 403 error?

Comment: No,its 200.                                                                                                 
Request Url: https://abcd.camm.com/efgh
Response Code: 200
File Download Completed!!!

Comment: What is the Output of your program

Comment: pasted above the output

Comment: And what does the file contain? If it's html, you can read it as text

Comment: Yes,its something like this

      var host = location.hostname;

      if(host.indexOf(portal)>=0)
      {
        window.location="something";

        }
      else
      {

                window.location="https://something"; 

      }